# Correct usage of Session.persist()

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm trying to understand the semantics of `Session.persist()`, and exactly what the entity manager does with unsaved transient instances. What I want to achieve is to just add a new transient instance to the session and have Hibernate execute an `INSERT` when the session is flushed.

I have found that if a new instance is persisted and then modified within the same session, the entity manager will generate both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements which can lead to constraint violations.

As an example, lets say I have an entity relation *Foo* with a `NOT NULL` column *bar* and the following service method.

```
@Transactional
void persistFoo(String bar) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    session.persist(foo);
    foo.setBar(bar);
}
```

Despite the fact that we provide a value for `bar`, executing this code will violate the *NULL* constraint in the database.

```
BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'bar'
```

The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-makingpersistent) states the following.

> persist() makes a transient instance persistent. However, it does not guarantee that the identifier value will be assigned to the persistent instance immediately, the assignment might happen at flush time...

The `INSERT` is indeed executed at the point the session is flushed at the end of the transactional block, but it is still parameterised with property values from the object *as it was* when `persist()` was called.

I know the particular problem this example illustrates can be fixed with some simple changes, but I'm more interested in trying to understand how its *supposed* to work.

My question is, is this behaviour just part of the contract of `Session.persist()` or can it be changed? If so, how do I tell the session to defer gathering parameters for the generated `INSERT` statement until the time when it is actually executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is part of the contract of `Session.persist()`. According to [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/internal/AbstractFlushingEventListener.html#performExecutions%28org.hibernate.event.spi.EventSource%29), this is the order in which SQLs are executed:

> 1. Inserts, in the order they were performed
> 2. Updates
> 3. Deletion of collection elements
> 4. Insertion of collection elements
> 5. Deletes, in the order they were performed

This order is part of the official Hibernate API, and applications rely on it when manipulating their entity graphs.

Putting changes that occurred after `Session.persist()` immediately to `INSERT` statements would break this contract and would cause problems in some use cases.

Let's suppose that we have a `User` entity, and it is possible that two users are associated with each other in some way. Then we can insert the two in one transaction:

```
persist(user1);
persist(user2);
user1.setPartner(user2);
user2.setPartner(user1);
```

If everything was stored in `INSERT` statements, then we would get foreign key constraint violation when persisting `user1`.

In general, by ensuring that only the state that was passed to `persist` ends up in `INSERT`, Hibernate gives us more flexibility to satisfy underlying DB constraints.

I am not aware of any config with which this behavior can be changed. Of course, as you mentioned, you can restructure your code so that `persist` is called after all the values are set, provided that no DB constraints are violated.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. I must have missed this part of the docs.