# JPA: CascadeType.PERSIST with ManyToOne

Tags: jpa, many-to-one

I am using CascadeType.PERSIST with ManyToOne

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="Article")
private Article article;
```

Persistence code is as:

```
    Article article = new Article();
    article.setAuthor("Article Author");
    article.setTitle("Article Title");
    Comment comm1 = new Comment();
    comm1.setAuthor("Author1");
    comm1.setTitle("Title1");
    article.addComment(comm1);
    em.persist(comm1);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I expected that using CascadeType.PERSIST on field would make persistence provider to sequence SQLs in such order that parent(Article here) is persisted first, and then child entities. But instead I get

> Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

What is proper way to go about in this case?

Article:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Article.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Article a")
public class Article implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private int id;

private String author;

private String title;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Comment
@OneToMany(mappedBy="article",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

public List<Comment> getComments() {
    return this.comments;
}

public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

public Comment addComment(Comment comment) {
    getComments().add(comment);
    comment.setArticle(this);

    return comment;
}

........
```

Comment:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Comment.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Comment c")
public class Comment implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String author;

private String title;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Article
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="Article")
private Article article;

......
```

Following works fine:

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Article article = new Article();
    article.setAuthor("Article Author");
    article.setTitle("Article Title");
    em.persist(article);
```

Comment: How is article's ID generated? There's no `@GeneratedValue` on it and you didn't set it in the "Persistence code" snippet. Did you omit it? Otherwise that is the issue.

Comment: If I just persist an Article without explicitly setting id (code added in original post)it works fine...so I guess id generation is not an issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the order in which entities are persisted determines the order in which `insert` statements are generated, so everything behaves as documented. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30462355/4754790) also for more details.

`Comment` is persisted first (you explicitly persist it first), then `Article` would be persisted by cascade.

The correct approach is to persist `Article` first, as you already pointed out.