# Why does Hibernate create two queries from a persist call?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="tableGenerator")
  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  //getters and setters...
```

}

and the following unit test method:

```
 public void testCreatePerson() {
    Person p1 = new Person();
    em.persist(p1);
    p1.setName("John Doe");
}
```

When I execute this test Hibernate generates two queries:

```
Hibernate: insert into Person (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update Person set name=? where id=?
```

It is not clear for me, that why is it needed to generate two queries (an insert and an update), instead of a simple insert. Does anyone have an idea?

Thank You,

p.s.:if I change the order of `em.persist(p1);` and `p1.setName("John Doe");` then only one insert is generated, but in my opinion it shouldn't matter, because the same defered insert could be used in both cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct usage of Session.persist()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307437/correct-usage-of-session-persist)

Comment: clearly it is not "needed" to do that in 2 statements, as long as the INSERT has not been fired off before the setXXX is called. I'd be pretty sure that other JPA providers won't be doing multiple statements for that.

Comment: @NeilStockton I think the same. The insert statement was not flushed before the `p1.setName("John Doe");` statement, so in my opinion a simple insert would have been enough in all the cases.